# want to search a record from table based on search string

Tags: oracle, java-stored-procedures

We want to search a record from table based on search string.
This search is a part of Stored procedure.

Following is what we need: 
1.  In table ppl there is column name which contains data in format of name,surname 
Say records are 
barack,oba
bar,obama 
and barack,obama.

1. We want to select record based on search string. Search string can be name OR surname.
2. We want exact search based on search string. 
   Means if search string is bar; it should not return barack,obama record and should only return only bar,obama. 
   Similar exact search for surname part.
3. We don’t know if the search string will have name or surname. 
   So search string can even be “oba” ..and it should return only “barack,oba” record.

Following approaches we have tried untill now; but none of these worked :

1. select name from ppl where name like 'bar,%' or name like '%,bar';
   This is working for name part but not working for surname part.

select name from ppl where name like 'oba,%' or name like '%,oba';
is not giving proper results.

1. select name from ppl where name = ANY('%,oba',oba,%'); - not working
2. select name from ppl where regexp_like (name,'^,oba$') OR regexp_like (name,'oba$,^'); - not working

I request you to share your thoughts in this case.

Comment: I don't understand why you say `name like 'bar,%' or name like '%,bar'` doesn't work.  It does for me.  Of course, you don't have anyone with the surname 'bar'...

Comment: It is not working for surname part means name like '%,oba' or name like 'oba,%' not working :(

Comment: Are there any more conditions in the query?  You can't successfully mix ANDs and ORs without using parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a regular expression (REGEX).

There are many sites that describe how to use them for example:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_regular_expressions.htm

http://orafaq.com/node/2404

For the examples you have described (as that's all i have to go on) you could use:

```
SELECT name_column
  FROM ppl
 WHERE REGEXP_INSTR(name_column, '^.*'||v_name||'(, *|$).*', 1, 1, 0, 'c') > 0;
```

Programatically substituting **v_name** for your name string. If the name string is to be searched case insensitively then:

```
SELECT name_column
  FROM ppl
 WHERE REGEXP_INSTR(name_column, '^.*'||v_name||'(, *|$).*', 1, 1, 0, 'i') > 0;
```

EDIT: You could probably use REGEXP_LIKE better than REGEXP_INSTR but I had somethig similar to hand.

e.g. Case insensitive:

```
SELECT name_column
  FROM ppl
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name_column, '^.*'||v_name||'(, *|$).*', 'i');
```

Case sensitive:

```
SELECT name_column
  FROM ppl
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name_column, '^.*'||v_name||'(, *|$).*', 'c');
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample data and SQL your question I can't see that you have a problem:

First I replicated your table and data (using SQL Plus):

```
SQL> create table ppl (name varchar2(30));

Table created.

SQL> insert into ppl values ('barack,oba');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ppl values ('bar,obama');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ppl values ('barack,obama');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from ppl;

NAME                                                                            
------------------------------                                                  
barack,oba                                                                      
bar,obama                                                                       
barack,obama
```

Now your queries:

```
SQL> select * from ppl where name like 'bar,%' or name like '%,bar';

NAME                                                                            
------------------------------                                                  
bar,obama
```

That's correct.

```
SQL> select * from ppl where name like 'oba,%' or name like '%,oba';

NAME                                                                            
------------------------------                                                  
barack,oba
```

That's also correct.

So what results do you get?